# Open an html file programatically using javascript in a new browser tab from disk

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, input

Is there a way to open an html file using javascript in a new tab?

I would want the user to select an html file using the `<input type="file">`. After selecting a file, some JavaScript code will open that html file.

Comment: Do a Google search for "jquery lightbox" and you'll find a whole bunch of ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @Charles, you should specify what's your objective? Opening the file for displaying html? Load the file in a DIV?

Comment: No i would want it to be displayed in a new tab, i know it sounds silly because a user can just double click the html file and open it. 
in case its not possible, i would like to know on how to achieve loading the file in a DIV

Comment: @Brad, the OP changed the question after my comment. The original question was extremely vague.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the File API for that. You could do something like the following example.

[**Here is a live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/peufjmnd/)

Tested it only in the latest Chrome & Firefox versions.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="">
    <p><input type="file" id="userFile"></p>
</form>

<p><a href="" target="_blank" id="newTab" style="display:none">Open File</a></p>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
(function(window, undefined) {
  var 
    doc = window.document,
    userFile = doc.getElementById('userFile'),
    newTab = doc.getElementById('newTab'),
    preview = doc.getElementById('preview'),
    fileReader = new FileReader();
  
  var fileutil = {
    init: function() {
      userFile.addEventListener('change', fileutil.onchange, false);
    },
    
    onchange: function(e) {
      //console.log(this.files);
      fileutil.create(this.files[0]);
    },
    
    create: function(file) {
      //console.log(file);
      var iframe = doc.createElement('iframe');

      // Start reading file..., and wait to complete.
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);      
      
      // When done reading.
      fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        //console.log(e.target.result);
        
        iframe.src = e.target.result;
        iframe.width = '100%';
        iframe.height = 500;
        
        newTab.href = e.target.result;
        newTab.style.display = 'block';
        
        preview.appendChild(iframe);
      };
    }
  };
  
  fileutil.init();
}(this));
```

UPDATE:
-------
This example gives access to the iframe's document, therefore allowing you to communicate with it and change its contents.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxx56hh4/

**JS:**

```
(function(window, undefined) {
  var 
    doc = window.document,
    userFile = doc.getElementById('userFile'),
    preview = doc.getElementById('preview'),
  
    // We read the file as Text and then parse it into a DOM Document.
    fileReader = new FileReader(),
    domParser = new DOMParser();
  
  var fileutil = {
    init: function() {
      userFile.addEventListener('change', fileutil.onchange, false);
    },
    
    onchange: function(e) {
      fileutil.create(this.files[0]);
    },
    
    create: function(file) {
      var self = this;

      // An iframe to append the new Document to.
      this.iframe = doc.createElement('iframe');
      this.iframe.width = '100%';
      this.iframe.height = 300;

      // Start reading the file as plain text and wait to complete.
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
      
      // When done reading.
      fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState === 2) { // 2 means DONE
          preview.appendChild(self.iframe);
          fileutil._ready(e.target.result);
        }
      };
    },
      
    _ready: function(ihtml) {
      var iwindow = this.iframe.contentWindow;
      var idocument = iwindow.contentDocument || iwindow.document;
        
      // Create a DOM document out of the text contents.
      var fileDocument = domParser.parseFromString(ihtml, "text/html");
      
      // Make the iframe's body equal the fileDocument's body.
      // We do this so we get only the body's contents and not the whole document.
      idocument.body.innerHTML = fileDocument.body.innerHTML;
      
      
      // We can now communicate with the iframe's body to add or remove elements.
      // With jQuery you can do: 
      // `$(idocument.body).prepend('<h1>Injected H1.</h1>')`
      // 
      // NOTE: Any resources such as stylesheets, images, and scripts referenced in fileDocument may not be available in the iframe.
      // 
      // With VanillaJS you can do:
      idocument.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<h1>Injected H1.</h1>');
        
      // Using XHR2 you can now send the original file or DOMString to your server.
      // More here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-sending
    }
  };
  
  fileutil.init();
}(this));
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="">
    <p><input type="file" id="userFile"></p>
</form>

<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: hi sir @istos. i have a problem with this approach
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

when the html file is loaded to a new tab or in iframe.
the cookies of that html file cannot be access. is there any other way that i could still access the cookies of that html file?

Comment: Nope that's not possible as it would be considered a Security hole in the Browser. A site in one tab/iframe can't access the data of another site.

Comment: thanks sir @istos.
btw, when i try to modify the content of the loaded html via jquery.
it gives me this error.
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

probably because of fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
do you have any idea sir on how i can modify the contents of the loaded html in iframe?

Comment: Please check my update to the answer. I think from here you are in a good position to figure out anything else that you want to do with the code on your own. If you have any other questions, please open a new question linking to this one too.